# Rails 4 - Bootstrap and CSS not showing on production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, asset-pipeline

The bootstrap and CSS work perfectly in development for our `rails 4.2` app.

Here is the login page in development:
[image]

After deploying (ubuntu 14.1), assets are precompiled with:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

However the bootstrap and css are completely not showing any effect on production server. Here is the same login page in production:

[image]

The `assets precompile` seems not having any effect on production. What's could cause bootstrap and css not showing in production? Is there way to verify that the assets precompile is successful?

UPDATE: files under app/assets 
[image]

Comment: if you precompile - you then need to commit them... did you?

Comment: Try clearing the cache as well : `rake RAILS_ENV=production tmp:cache:clear`

Comment: Also - are bootstrap etc added to your list of assets to precompile? Relevant section of guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-production

Comment: try to run in production mode locally and see if css works properly.

Comment: The assets precompile was done on production server. The public/assets dir was deleted before each assets precompile.

Comment: `@Pardeep Saini`, running production locally has no bootstrap and css.

Comment: `@Taryn East `, all bootstrap added to production.rb (see comment below) and they are fingerprinted under /assets. However the result is the same. Tried clear cache and no luck. Not sure what else we missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  # Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
  # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )
```

You might have to uncomment the above lines and add the js and css files you are compiling. Above line should be present in `/config/environments/production.rb`

Comment: Just posted files under app/assets. According to the comment, `all non-JS/CSS are already added`. It seems that all files under app/assets should have been included already. BTW

Comment: `config.assets.precompile += ['bootstrap.min.js', 'bootstrap-theme.min.css',  'bootstrap.min.css', 'simple_form.css.scss', 'user_menus.css.scss']` is added `production.rb.`. These 3 bootstrap related files are showing in the assets subdir after precompile. But there is no change on html page. Not sure what we still missed.

Comment: Tried to put precompile string array in config/initializers/assets.rb as Rails doc specifies. Still not picking up.

Comment: You need to include the compiled assets to your Web page. Make sure you use the link_to tag so that it picks up the compiled assets.